# Pip Install Error Could Not Find A Version(although version is availiable)

Tags: python, flask, installation, pip, requirements.txt

I am getting a strange error when running `pip install -r requirements.txt` which is

```
Flask==0.11
flask-mongoengine==0.8.2
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
jsonschema==2.5.1
mongoengine==0.11
py-bcrypt==0.4
pymongo==3.4.0
```

python version is 3.8.6, running on Windows, 64bit

The error message is bizarre:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-mongoengine==0.8.2 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.5, 1.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask-mongoengine==0.8.2

Update:
Tried `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` but didn't work.

Update2:
I am very new to docker(first day), but originally I ran into this error runnin docker-compose build. I got `distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('rednose')`

Update 3:
It works outside of virtual environment

Comment: There may be an invisible (and incorrect) character somewhere in the file near the 0.8.2. Have you tried `pip install flask-mongoengine==0.8.2` directly on the command line? (Type it in full; if it is an invisible character issue, copy-paste will include the bad character.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I typed it in but no luck, same error.

Comment: What are the Python version, the OS, the CPU bitness, the CPU architecture, etc.?

Comment: @sinoroc, Hi, python version is 3.8.6, running on Windows, 64bit. I started learning docker today, I wonder if it has anything to do with that. I previously worked on a project with flask-mongoengine 0.7.4 with no such an issue. awkward

Comment: Don't know for sure, but maybe that version of the library is too old and not compatible with Python 3.8. Maybe this `requirments.txt` was written with a much older Python version in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem for a while with flask-mongoengine==0.9.5 and solved it by installing wheel (specifically version==0.36.2 in my case) before installing flask-mongoengine. wheel is prerequisite of this package as the [pypi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/flask-mongoengine/) mentioned.